# How to visualise the total electron density from a Gaussian 16 calculation?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I am trying to generate a 3D visualisation of the total electron density of a molecule. Using Gaussian 16, I have optimised this structure, with DFT, and formatted the resulting `.chk` file into a `.fchk` using the [`formchk`](http://gaussian.com/formchk/) utility. I have used the [`cubegen`](http://gaussian.com/cubegen/) utility:

```
cubegen 0 fdensity=scf molecule.fchk molecule.cube -5 h <0.20_3d_cube.xyz
```

to generate a `.cube` file with 0.20 angstrom spacing about a cube of the molecule.

However, the resulting `.cube` file fails to visualise any total electron density in visualisation software. Gaussview 6 fails to create a surface, prompting an error:

> Surface build failed! Processing mesh, No data to plot. IsoValue may be out of range

VMD allows the visualisation of an isosurface, but visually nothing appears.

Comment: Can you try with npts -1 instead of -5? According to the gaussian manual it has to be set to -1 in case you are using the cubefile2 option

Comment: The syntax appears to be in order. I have never used this approach before, i.e. specifying the box manually. Have you tried something simpler, like `cubegen 0 fdensity=scf molecule.fchk molecule.cube -4 h`? Did that work? You should be able to visualise the scf density from within GV only reading in the output, checkpoint, or formatted checkpoint file.

Comment: You can also visualize the electron density directly in Avogadro using just the fchk file. See this video for a short (3 min) tutorial. [youtube tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AviNr4MiLww)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When GaussView gives you the error

> Surface build failed! Processing mesh, No data to plot. IsoValue may be out of range

it means that the data in your `.cube` file doesn't have values of density at that isovalue. So when it tries to plot a surface, it cannot plot anything.

The IsoValue (default is `0.00040`, I believe) means that you construct a surface at every place in the density where the density equals the IsoValue ('iso' = 'same'). So for the default, it opens up your `.cube` file and looks for the cube coordinates that have density at (or near) `0.00040`, and plots a surface that connects these points (this is your 'mesh').

Most likely, your density values are too <s>small</s> large to plot an isosurface at this value. Try making the default density isovalue in GaussView to be something <s>smaller</s> larger and go from there. (Practically, I'd keep shifting an order of magnitude until a surface builds, e.g. try a value of `0.004` next).

Even better, you should look into the `.cube` file itself to see what your volumetric data looks like. The first few lines define the grid spacing and dimensions of the cube, but then you will see a bunch of floating point values. Here's an example `.cube` I took from [this site](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/cube/) (also a good reference):

```
CPMD CUBE FILE.
 OUTER LOOP: X, MIDDLE LOOP: Y, INNER LOOP: Z
    3    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
   40    0.283459    0.000000    0.000000
   40    0.000000    0.283459    0.000000
   40    0.000000    0.000000    0.283459
    8    0.000000    5.570575    5.669178    5.593517
    1    0.000000    5.562867    5.669178    7.428055
    1    0.000000    7.340606    5.669178    5.111259
 -0.25568E-04  0.59213E-05  0.81068E-05  0.10868E-04  0.11313E-04  0.35999E-05
      :             :             :           :            :            :
      :             :             :           :            :            :
      :             :             :           :            :            :
        In this case there will be 40 x 40 x 40 floating point values
      :             :             :           :            :            :
      :             :             :           :            :            :
      :             :             :           :            :            :
```

Look at the value of your floating point numbers at the end. As a starting point, pick a number for your isovalue that is about an order of magnitude less than your largest values, and adjust from there.

If your values are *all* at or near zero (so, practically speaking, on the order of `1E-8` or lower) then you need to revisit how you are generating the `.cube` file, since your cube is not capturing any density---then it's a `cubegen` issue not an isosurface issue.